# How to divide test cases effectively to automate them in a mobile app using appium

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, appium

I'm trying to automate test cases of an app containing about 5 big sections
I have a lot of test cases more that 100 in each one 
What is the best way to divide test cases in order to automate them?
I create separate 5 classes, and in each one i put all tests ?

For now i'm writing my test cases using dependence like the following example

```
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("This is method 2");
    }
```

But my problem if there is no methods dependence how should i proceed in order to make all tests cases executed automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

As I answered your another question, you can always use [Page Object Pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) to make your easier to read and what is the most important easier to fix, when it will be needed. Then, if needed you could change the variables in one place - not everywhere.

Regarding your question about using annotations  considering different class usage and methods inside them, please check below example:

```
@Test
public void checkSampleScreen() throws InterruptedException{

    SampleScreen ss = new SampleScreen(driver);
    ss.launchStartScreen();
    }
```